# Javascript file is never generated for Typings file. (*.d.ts)

Tags: typescript

The issue I have is the *.d.ts file never generated a javascript file *.js.  So, I don't know what is causing the issue here.

I also wonder if it is possible to just declare it in `MaskedInputDirective.ts` instead of needing the *.d.ts file.  Is that possible too?

[MaskedInputTypings.d.ts]

```
export function createTextMaskInputElement(a: any): any
export function conformToMask(a: any, b: any, c: any): any
```

[MaskedInputDirective.ts]

```
import { createTextMaskInputElement } from './MaskedInputTypings'
export { conformToMask } from './MaskedInputTypings'

export class MaskedInputDirective {
    private _textMaskInputElement: any;
    private _inputElement: HTMLInputElement;

    private setupMask() {
        if (this.inputElement) {
            this.textMaskInputElement = createTextMaskInputElement(
                Object.assign({inputElement: this.inputElement}, this.textMaskConfig)
            )
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need it? The exact reason for `.d.ts` files is to provide only type declarations for the typescript compiler for already existing javascript, e.g. for inbuilt functions or things like node.js, lodash, etc. The JS code is already there - no need to generate another one. And in addition to that `d.ts` files contain only type definitions - which have no counterpart in Javascript - so it's not possible to generate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some misunderstandings here. Declaration files (.d.ts files) are purely descriptive tools to annotate the structure of already existing packages (.js files).

Note the term. *Declaring* something is announcing to the compiler that some construct (a function, a variable) implicitly exists in scope through some other work you've done. *Defining* something is telling the compiler to create that construct (a function, a variable, etc.). If you are writing in typescript, you will rarely if ever need to manually construct .d.ts files for your own code because you don't need to announce the existence of something to the compiler if the compiler is responsible for creating it.

> I also wonder if it is possible to just declare it in MaskedInputDirective.ts instead of needing the *.d.ts file. Is that possible too?

Yes it is, but that assumes the functions `createTextMaskInputElement` and `conformToMask` **exist** somewhere in scope. Given that what you're creating is a **module** you shouldn't have access to those unless you explicitly import their definitions. Where are `createTextMaskInputElement` and `conformToMask` *defined*? Where is the function body?

If it's in some TS code that you've written, then you can import that .ts file directly. I believe this is the case given that you expect the .d.ts file to generate something. That would look like this:

[MaskedInputUtils.ts]

```
export function createTextMaskInputElement(a: any): any {
    // function implementation
}
export function conformToMask(a: any, b: any, c: any): any {
    // function implementation
}
```

[MaskedInputDirective.ts]

```
import { createTextMaskInputElement, conformToMask } from './MaskedInputUtils'

export class MaskedInputDirective {
    private _textMaskInputElement: any;
    private _inputElement: HTMLInputElement;

    private setupMask() {
        if (this.inputElement) {
            this.textMaskInputElement = createTextMaskInputElement(
                Object.assign({inputElement: this.inputElement}, this.textMaskConfig)
            )
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I have is the *.d.ts file never generated a javascript file *.d.js.

You should be getting a `.d.ts` and a **`.js`**. The `.d.ts` is for declarations and `.js` is for running. There is no `.d.js`.